# /system has self-destructed by itself

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-j5

*Posting on behalf of a friend. He is a little bit insane.*

Last night, I turned my phone off after listening to music. This morning, i turn it to receive the heart-warming message 'Please install an Operating system.' I thought that I could just flash my TWRP Backup - Recovery still works - but It does not work. I can't even detect the device on ODIN/Heimdall.

Help? I am No longer rooted (since /system has emptied itself)

Comment: I take it your friend is using a Samsung Galaxy j5. Samsung does not supply their phones with fastboot, but you can use heimdall instead to install CWM and go from there. Google "heimdall install CWM" for more. Other than that, you might even get Odin working and do the standard procedure from there.

Comment: @ionree Heimdall does not see it. Would've tried your method already otherwise (seen it before somewhere)

Comment: Just to make sure, you did put your phone in Download mode?

Comment: @ionree Yep. Blue background, info in the corner, ODIN MODE up top. Other than the blue background (it's usually black) its Download modr in all its glory

Comment: Okay, you have some hope left. I'm pretty sure I dealt with the same issue before on a Samsung device using Odin to flash CWM (you might find an Odin version of TWRP as well), enabling USB mass storage from within the recovery, copying the OS onto the device and flashing it. Also, heimdall should work. It's a bit janky sometimes as you have to manually install the libusb driver, maybe try again on a different USB port and make sure you are installing the driver to the correct device.